# Where to find the resulting .so file of a compilation?

Tags: compiling, compiler

I just compiled xdebug as instructed on the official site. But where can I find the resulting .so file?

I found one in the folder `./libs/xdebug.so` and one in `modules/xdebug.so`.

#### Questions

- Which one do I need, there is no info on the official site?
- Why is there not simply a folder called `result` or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last part of the build, as run by `make`, tells you explicitly where the library is installed:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /tmp/user/1000/xdebug/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the answer is that you want the `.so` which is `modules` (which is identical to the one in `.libs`, but the latter is a `libtool` implementation detail).

`make install` copies that `.so` into the target directory, which is the PHP API directory as determined by `phpize` (`/usr/lib/php/20151012` on the system I tested this on). PHP should be able to pick it up there automatically.

So really, if you follow [the upstream instructions](https://xdebug.org/docs/install) all the way to the end, you don’t need to care about the answer: `make install` does the right thing, making the module available to your PHP installation.